# Is it possible to use Eclipse Tycho in combination with Maven CI Friendly versions?

Tags: maven, tycho

Is anyone aware of a way to use [Tycho](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.tycho) in combination with [Maven CI Friendly versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have a clue what would be the right way to do this. Tycho expects a Bundle-Version property in the MANIFEST.MF file. I could set this to ${revision}, but then Tycho complains that this is not a valid OSGi version number...